# Android: Can replaceOrThrow() be used for inserting a new row in the SQLite database

Tags: android

Is it possible to use `replaceOrThrow()` to insert a new row into an Android SQLite DB?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, but there is an `insertOrThrow` method - [see the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

It uses the following params:

```
public long insertOrThrow (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it inserts a new row, but only if that doesn't exist.

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#replaceOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)):

> Inserts a new row if a row does not already exist.

Actually it tries to insert the supplied values first and in case of a conflict it does a replace. As you can see in [sources](https://sqlite.org/android/file?name=sqlite3/src/main/java/org/sqlite/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java&ci=253313a7ee8cc014) it calls `insertWithOnConflict`,

Answer (score 0):

following code worked fine for me, skd26. replace should function like an insert in most databases

```
if (comicBook == null) {

    return false;
}

long id = -1;

try {

    id = mDatabase.replaceOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, generateContentValuesFromObject(comicBook));
} catch (SQLException e) {
    Log.e("ComicBookFav", e.getMessage());
}

return id != -1;
```